# How to create a new theorem-like environment in Bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

In Bookdown, how can I create a new theorem-like environment called "model", with printed name "Model" and label prefix "mdl", so that following in the body of a .Rmd would yield expected output

```
::: {.model #foo}
A labeled model here.
:::

See my Model \@ref(mdl:foo)
```

I naively tried adding the following to my `preamble.tex` file (passed as a value to `in_header` in my .Rmd YAML header), but I didn't get the desired output.

```
\newcounter{model}
\newtheorem{model}[model]{Model}
```

- [Add axioms to theorem environments #1171](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1171) provide some clues. But this is beyond me
- [How to define a new theorem in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857215/how-to-define-a-new-theorem-in-bookdown) is a similar question, but didn't receive an answer.

If there's no easy way to do this, is there a reasonable hack?